# EF6/MVC5: References to Classes Not Part of DbContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I suddenly started receiving error messages from an MVC5 app that was previously working. Something deep in the NET libraries is complaining about certain classes (e.g., VoterInfo) "not having a key defined". Reference is also made to a DbSet called VoterInfoes.

But here's the thing: there is not class called VoterInfo anywhere in the solution. Nor is there the other class causing an error (BallotInfo) defined anywhere in the solution.

I've never encountered anything like this before. Why would VS2013 suddenly started defining objects for me?

Comment: Check your database for a table called voterinfo

Comment: I think these classes are in a dll you have a reference to and you refer to these classes in one of your entities.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using Code First, so the lack of classes by those names means there shouldn't be any table of those names defined in the database. That was one of the first things I checked, and, as expected, there's nothing by those names in the database.

Comment: In the debugger enable clr exceptions. This should tell you where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Learned something new: I had a class which derived from a class defined in the database "schema". Even though I did not incorporate the derived classes in the database, they were still being processed by Entity Framework. Which ultimately led to the errors I encountered.